# Getting rid of the blue background in a C# datagridview row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How do I get rid of the blue background when data is loaded into a datagridview, the first row has a default color of blue for the background, and when you select a row, the background changes to blue. I'd like it so that there is no blue background, at all.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "C# datagridview". Do you mean System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView? Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.DataGridView? Perhaps System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView?

Comment: Yes, a Winforms datagridview, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're working with the `DataGridView` control within a windows form application.  The blue background is the default color for a selected row.  You can change this color within the properties window

1. Select the `datagridview`
2. Within properties window, click elipses (...) next to `DefaultCellStyle`
3. Under `Appearance`, change the value of `SelectionBackColor`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking around at all different answers and this one did what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The blue background is the default color for a selected row in gridview. You can change this color within the properties window

```
Gridview1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red; or Color.Transparent
Gridview1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black; or Color.Transparent
```

but if you are **refreshing gridview in very short duration say less than 1 sec duration** in that case you have to cahnge the default color of added rows in Gridview,(above senario will work fine for  static gridview).

```
Gridview1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;  or Color.Transparent 
Gridview1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black;or Color.Transparent
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridView control has a [ClearSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.clearselection.aspx) method. Just call that and your top row is no longer selected.

Actually I think this is what you want to do rather than changing the SelectionBackColor as suggested by the other answer.